# Avoid dependency hell on docker

Tags: python, linux, docker

I build an AI application in Python involving quiet an amount of Python libraries. At this point, I would like to run my application inside of a docker container to make the AI App a service.

**What are my options concerning dependencie so that all necessary libraries are downloaded automatically?**

As an weak alternative, I tried this with a "requirement.txt" file on the same level as my Docker build file, but this didn't work.

Comment: How is your Dockerfile? Please post it here.

Comment: I suggest this question be given a different title. The problem is simply installing dependencies, and not what most people would understand by "dependency hell", and as such, it won't help other people with similar problems find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options. It depends a lot on the use case, the number of containers you will eventually build, production vs dev environment etc.

Generally if you have an AI application you will need a graphics card driver pre-installed on your host system for model training. Which means eventually you'll have to come up with a way to automate driver install or write instructions for end users to do that. For an app you might also need database drivers in the docker image, if your front or back end databases are outside the container. Here is a toned-down example of one of my uses cases with requirement being building docker for a data pipeline.

```
#Taken from puckel/docker-airflow
#can look up this image name on google to see which OS it is based on.
FROM python:3.6-slim-buster 
LABEL maintainer="batman"

# Never prompt the user for choices on installation/configuration of packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TERM linux

# Set some default configuration for data pipeline management tool called airflow
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.9
ARG AIRFLOW_USER_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
ARG AIRFLOW_DEPS=""
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}

# here install some linux dependencies required to run the pipeline. 
# use apt-get install, apt-get auto-remove etc to reduce size of image
# curl and install sql server odbc driver for my linux
RUN set -ex \
    && buildDeps=' freetds-dev libkrb5-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev libpq-dev git' \
    && apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get upgrade -yqq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
        $buildDeps freetds-bin build-essential default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        apt-utils curl rsync netcat locales gnupg wget \
    && useradd -ms /bin/bash -d ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME} airflow \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \ #
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools \
    && pip install apache-airflow[crypto,celery,postgres,hive,jdbc,mysql,ssh${AIRFLOW_DEPS:+,}${AIRFLOW_DEPS}]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -yqq $buildDeps \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf \
        /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        /tmp/* \
        /var/tmp/* \
        /usr/share/man \
        /usr/share/doc \
        /usr/share/doc-base

# Install all required packages in python environment from requirements.txt (I generally remove version numbers if my python version are same)
ADD ./requirements.txt /config/
RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.txt


# CLEANUP
RUN apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf \
    /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    /tmp/* \
    /var/tmp/* \
    /usr/share/man \
    /usr/share/doc \
    /usr/share/doc-base


#CONFIGURATION
COPY script/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY config/airflow.cfg ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}/airflow.cfg

# hand ownership of libraries to relevant user
RUN chown -R airflow: ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}

#expose ports to outside container for web app access
EXPOSE 8080 5555 8793

USER airflow
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["webserver"]
```

1) Select an appropriate base image which has the operating system you need.
2) Get your gpu drivers installed if you are training a model, not mandatory if you are serving the model

Answer (score 2):

Your Dockerfile will need instructions to install the requirements, e.g.

```
COPY requirement.txt requirement.txt
RUN pip install -r requirement.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the very useful comments:

My dockerfile:

```
# Python 3.7.3
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY greeter_server.py /app
COPY AspenTechClient.py /app
COPY OpcUa_pb2.py /app
COPY OpcUa_pb2_grpc.py /app
COPY helloworld_pb2.py /app
COPY helloworld_pb2_grpc.py /app
COPY Models.py /app

ADD ./requirement.txt /app


# Training & Validation data  we need 
RUN mkdir -p /app/output

RUN pip install -r requirement.txt
#RUN pip3 install grpcio grpcio-tools
#RUN pip install protobuf
#RUN pip install pandas
#RUN pip install scipy

#expose ports to outside container for web app access
EXPOSE 10500

# Argument to python command
CMD [ "python", "/app/greeter_server.py" ]
```

By the tips here, I already added the extra lines for "requirement.txt" and that works like a charm. Thank you very much!

- Since I only want to run a deployment in the container, I will forseen trained models so no need for a GPU. For this I have a local machine. With an appropriate mount I deliver the .h5 to the container.

@pyeR_biz: Thank you very much for the tips about pipelines. This is something I didn't have experience with but certainly will do it in the near future.